# RTK Query redirect status 303

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, rtk-query

I'm making a POST request to the server with RTK Query.
I received a 303 status in response with the Location header, to which I need to redirect.
If I understand correctly, the redirect should be performed automatically, but it does not happen.

```
    endpointName: builder.mutation<any, { id: string }>({
       query: ({ id }) => ({
         url: `${ApiRoutes.APPLICATION}/${id}${ApiRoutes.PAY}`,
         method: 'POST',
         redirect: 'follow',
         responseHandler: (response) => {
            console.log(response); //status=200, redirected=true
         },
       })
     }),
```

If you look at the responseHandler logs, there is status 200 redirected
But in dev tools i received a 303 status in response with the Location header, to which I need to redirect.

What's my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: _"If I understand correctly, the redirect should be performed automatically"_ - what you are saying with `redirect: 'follow'`, is that this _background request_ should automatically follow redirects. _Because_ you said it should do that, you only get to see the final 200 status code as a result here. You must make this _not_ follow location headers, and then extract the URL _from_ the received Location header, so that you can then redirect the _frontend_ there yourself (f.e. via assignment to `location.href`.)

Comment: The alternative would be that you do _not_ redirect from the server side (assuming that component is also under your control), but return the target URL as part of a JSON response - then your client-side code can easily read it from there (bit easier than to start going through the response headers.)

Comment: Flows like that also work well with forms. <form action={`${ApiRoutes.APPLICATION}/${id}${ApiRoutes.PAY}`} method="POST"><button >Get redirected</button></form>

Comment: Making the fetch request in JS will not give you the default behaviour of redirecting the user agent, the form on the other hand is meant to handle post => redirect flows